# Efficiently subtract the mean off the columns of a sparse matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Say, we have a scipy sparse matrix

```
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
mat = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([[0, 1, 2]
                               [0, -1, 3]])
```

The columnar means are `0, 0, 2.5`
So the result after subtracting the columnar means from each element of a column should be,

```
[
   [0, 1, -.5]
   [0, -1, .5]
]
```

As the matrices are huge, is there an efficient way, i.e. without using `.toarray()` to calculate it?

Comment: Why not use numpy array?

Comment: Define huge please

Comment: It also depends on the type of sparse format you use.

Comment: Will the mean of most of the columns be 0?

Comment: Are you subtracting the mean from the 0s as well?

Comment: If you have constructed scipy sparse matrices, show them.  Don't give us lists or pseudo-numpy arrays.  Show the code you have used, even if you don't think it is efficient or suitable for large matrices.

Comment: @hpaulj Updated to show the code being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no efficient way, because unless your means are almost all zero the resulting matrix will not be sparse.

Your only option is to carry this information separately forward (e.g. as a constant offset per column) and change your algorithm(s) appropriately, or to switch to a dense matrix.